# Add help button to form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form with minimize/maximize buttons on the toolbar so I cant have a help button there.

So I thought I would add a normal button and add code on the click event to show the help cursor and show the help text on the controls exactly as the help button does on the toolbar.

I can change the cursor to show the question mark but this doesn't do anything else, how can I 'activate' the help function?

Answer (score 3):

You first have to create one, have a look at the `Helpprovider class`:

[Msdn HelpProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx)

[HelpProvider example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/helpprovider-in-C-Sharp/)

But, you can also create a `simple form`, add a `webbrowser control` to it. Then create a `.html` file and insert it in the `webbrowser control`, when the user clicks the `help button`, the `form` will open with the `.html` page with your help text.

You can set a shortcut in the property's window for the button that opens the helpfunction like this:
[image]

The F1 button will call the code behind the helpbutton that calls the help function.

Comment: thanks, yes I have got the help provider control but how do I 'activate' the help function like you would if you pressed the help button on the form bar?

Comment: thanks again, but is there a way of doing the following: click the help button (this turns the cursor to the help cursor), then whatever control I click on while the cursor is in the 'help mode' it displays the help assigned to that control. This is the functionality I would have if the form displayed the standard help button on the title bar